# Attempting to automate the upload of application code to Dreamfactory DSP

Tags: node.js, file-upload, http-post, postman

I have a build process using NPM/Gulp that builds/minifies/etc an Angular app.

I am attempting to put a deploy step in the build process that produces a zip file and uploads it to my Dreamfactory DSP's filestorage and unzips it.

I see the REST API has a method for uploading files, cleaning and extracting, so that is what I'm trying to do.

So, I first simply wanted to get a post working from something like Postman in order to verify the URL, parameters, headers, etc.  So, here is what I have:

```
URL: https://<mydspname>.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/files/applications/app.zip?clean=true&extract=true

Headers:
X-DreamFactory-Application-Name: <app name>
X-DreamFactory-Session-Token: <valid session token>
```

I then, in Postman, select a binary body and attach a small/sample zip file.

After invoking the post, I get this response:

```
{
  "folder": {
    "name": ".",
    "path": "."
  }
}
```

It does seem to upload the file and extract it, but it extracts it at the root of the applications container.

[image]

How can I

1. have it be extracted into a sub-folder of applications (without necessarily introducing an artificial folder into the zip itself)?
2. not prepend the file name that it extracts with a "."?  (see screenshot)

Comment: hey steve, the support engineers at dreamfactory can help you. contact support at dreamfactory.com